# xslt to group like items by name at multiple nesting levels

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to get a grouping optimization to work with xslt. The optimization should gather items with the same name into a single items element. I have it working when the items are all at the same level, but some of the input has them nested at arbitrary levels and I can't figure out how to get the grouping to work in these cases.

Here's a working example:

```
<process>
<op>
    <group>
        <op>
            <item>
                <name>a</name>
                <detail><value>1</value></detail>
            </item>
        </op>
        <op>
            <item>
                <name>a</name>
                <detail><value>2</value></detail>
            </item>
        </op>
        <op>
            <item>
                <name>c</name>
                <name>x1</name>
                <detail><value>3</value></detail>
            </item>
        </op>
    </group>
</op>
```

And here is my example transform definition:

```
<xs:template match="group[op[item[detail]]]">
    <xs:copy>
        <xs:for-each-group select="op" group-by="item/name">
            <op><item>
            <xs:copy-of select="item/name"/>
            <xs:choose>
            <xs:when test="count(current-group()) &gt; 1">
            <details>
            <xs:for-each select="current-group()">
                <detail><value>
                <xs:value-of select="item/detail/value"/>
                </value></detail>
            </xs:for-each>
            </details>
            </xs:when>
            <xs:otherwise>
                <detail><value>
                <xs:value-of select="item/detail/value"/>
                </value></detail>
            </xs:otherwise>
            </xs:choose>
            </item></op>
        </xs:for-each-group>
    </xs:copy>
</xs:template>

<xs:template match="@*|node()">
    <xs:copy>
        <xs:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xs:copy>
</xs:template>
```

Which correctly groups the "a" items together, leaving the "c" item separate.
However, if the "a" items are nested further, they getted dropped out of the result:

```
<process>
<op>
    <group>
        <op>
            <group>
                <op>
                    <item>
                        <name>a</name>
                        <detail><value>1</value></detail>
                    </item>
                </op>
                <op>
                    <item>
                        <name>a</name>
                        <detail><value>2</value></detail>
                    </item>
                </op>
            </group>
        </op>
        <op>
            <item>
                <name>c</name>
                <name>x1</name>
                <detail><value>3</value></detail>
            </item>
        </op>
    </group>
</op>
```

The desired resulting XML would be:

```
<process>
<op>
    <group>
        <op>
            <group>
                <op>
                    <item>
                        <name>a</name>
                        <details>
                            <detail><value>1</value></detail>
                            <detail><value>2</value></detail>
                        </details>
                    </item>
                </op>
            </group>
        </op>
        <op>
            <item>
                <name>c</name>
                <name>x1</name>
                <detail><value>3</value></detail>
            </item>
        </op>
    </group>
</op></process>
```

(if multiple entries with 'c' and 'x1' both exist they could also be grouped as well, but this is not a requirement)

Comment: You need to show and explain which result you want for the last input sample you have, that is not clear to me.

Comment: added desired resulting xml

Comment: So you want to preserve the hierarchy and basically group `op` elements inside each `group`. What happens if there are some `op` elements with an `item` `c`, then a nested group, then some `op` elements with an `item` `c`? Do you want to group all `c` items together, basically pulling up the latter elements? Or do you only want to group `op` elements with the same `item` if they are adjacent in the original XML?

Comment: Only adjacent in the original xml is the need.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to group all elements and make sure those that don't have a key are processed recursively, here is one attempt to do that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group[op[item[detail]]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="string(item/name)">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() eq ''">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:copy>
                <item>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="item/name"/>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                      <details>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/item/detail"/>
                      </details>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                       <xsl:copy-of select="item/detail"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </item>
              </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there can be multiple `name` elements forming the grouping key then with XSLT 2.0 an approach can be to compute `string-join(item/name, '|')` as the key (where the bar `|` should be replaced by a suitable separator character for which it is ensured it does not occur in `name`s). Here is an example that first sorts the `name`s to make sure both `<name>a</name><name>b</name>` and `<name>b</name><name>a</name>` are grouped:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:param name="separator" as="xs:string" select="'|'"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:sort" as="xs:string*">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:perform-sort select="$input">
    <xsl:sort select="."/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group[op[item[detail]]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="string-join(mf:sort(item/name), $separator)">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() eq ''">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:copy>
                <item>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="item/name"/>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                      <details>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/item/detail"/>
                      </details>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                       <xsl:copy-of select="item/detail"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </item>
              </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works for all my test cases except where some items have multiple name elements (which I didn't include the sample, sorry). It errors out on the string() call when multiple names exist. It should only combine the items if all names match.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show a sample and the corresponding result with multiple names? Are these names sorted or sortable? I am thinking of using e.g. `group-by="string-join(item/name, '|')"` which would only work if the names are sorted or at least can be sorted to get a kind of finger print to group the ancestor by.